# DataTables: When scroll bar of tbody is hidden, fixed column gets messed up

Tags: jquery, datatables, fixed-header-tables

I've got a table which includes:

1. first Column is fixed
2. tfoot
3. horizontal scroll bar of tfoot
4. have hidden horizontal scroll bar of tbody.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jbeteta/6sxh3gbk/12/

[image]

```
    $(function() {
              $('#example').DataTable({         
            "fnInitComplete": function () {
                        // Disable scrolling in Head
                        $('.dataTables_scrollHead').css({
                            'overflow-y': 'hidden !important'
                        });

                        // Disable TBODY scroll bars
                        $('.dataTables_scrollBody').css({
                            'overflow-y': 'scroll',
                            'overflow-x': 'hidden',
                            'border': 'none'
                        });

                        // Enable TFOOT scoll bars
                        $('.dataTables_scrollFoot').css('overflow', 'auto');

                        //  Sync TFOOT scrolling with TBODY
                        $('.dataTables_scrollFoot').on('scroll', function () {
                            $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
                        });

                    },
                scrollX: true,
                paging: true,
                fixedColumns: {
                  leftColumns: 1
                }
 });
        });
```

In that scenario, when you scroll to the right side, you will see that last row cell of fixed Column (background color: red) get messed up, because horizontal `<tbody>` scroll bar is hidden.

My question: Is there any way to correct this?

By the way: I had to hide `<tbody>` horizontal scroll bar because it doesn't get syncronized with `<tfoot>` scroll bar.

Many thanks

EDIT: In Chrome is the same:

[image]

Comment: I don't see the problem you have stated in the fiddle

Comment: What browser do you use? I'm using Mozilla and IE, and the problem is still there

Comment: Oh.. I was testing on Chrome and I don't see the issue.

Comment: I have used Chrome as well and problem persist. I attached image. Don't you see this kind of mess when you scroll to the right?

Comment: hi. i dont see your code is wrong, check this https://jsfiddle.net/6sxh3gbk/17/

Comment: Disable TBODY scroll bars and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a *partly* solution. The entire setup is a huge mix of different tables and divs. For some reason the hidden scrollbars still is in "effect" for several of the divs, i.e they still take up space and react when other elements is being scrolled. Perhaps really, really careful try and error CSS-ing on each element / container could solve the overall problem, but to me it seems like expected browser behaviour, simply "as it is". But on webkit-browsers you can do this :

```css3
div:not(.dataTables_scrollFoot)::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none; 
}
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/6sxh3gbk/19/**

This will effectively disable all the nasty hidden (but not really hidden) scrollbars on the injected `<div>` elements, but preserve them on the footer element which we want to scroll with.

But this does only apply to [webkit browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar):  Chrome, chromium, Safari, Opera and Android.

Gecko (mozilla) once had a similar feature `-moz-scrollbars-none` but it was deprecated and left out. AFAIK there is a permanent cry for bringing it back.

This is also the case for Edge, the [issue is still being raised](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11212391/). For Edge there is real hope, since MS many times have stated that EdgeHTML is meant to be fully compatible with the WebKit layout engine.

So a partly solution, covering perhaps 85%, all devices included.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and your answer, davidkonrad. It helped me a lot.

Comment: David, just trying, and it also hides ".dataTables_scrollBody". Any chance to not hide it?

Comment: @Delmonte, do you mean the vertical scrollbar in `.dataTables_scrollBody` ? Or which browser / platform ..?

Comment: Yes, that one... the vertical scrollbar in .dataTables_scrollBody In Chrome browser.

Comment: Is this better? `div:not(.dataTables_scrollFoot):not(.dataTables_scrollBody)::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }` https://jsfiddle.net/6sxh3gbk/20/

Answer (score 0):

Please check..

1. first Column is fixed
2. tfoot
3. horizontal scroll bar of tfoot
4. have hidden horizontal scroll bar of tbody.

this problem has been solved.
Your ans is given below link..

```
$(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable({         
     scrollY:        "300px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false,
    fixedColumns:   {
        leftColumns: 1
    }
      });
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sxh3gbk/15/)

Comment: OP wants to have the scrollbar BELOW the footer.  That is the problem. It is actually a really good question.

Comment: @davidkonrad yes.. you're right.. but he has also another problem regarding tbody height.. i think that problem has been solved in above answer.